# Basic Induction Problem

Tags: induction

For $N \geq 4$, prove $2^N \geq N^2$.

I have the base case, $N=K$, and $N=K+1$ steps, but I am stuck at this point...

$2^K\cdot 2 \geq (K+1)^2$

Thanks!

Comment: Must N be a whole number?

Comment: I believe _N_ has to be a natural number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've already done the base case, so let's do the induction step.

**Induction Hypothesis:** Suppose that $2^N \geq N^2$ for $N = K$, where $K \geq 4$.

It remains to prove that $2^{K+1} \geq (K+1)^2$. Indeed, observe that:
\begin{align*}
2^{K+1} &= 2(2^K) \\
&\geq 2(K^2) &\text{by the induction hypothesis} \\
&= K^2 + (\color{red}{K})K \\
&\geq K^2 + (\color{red}{4})K &\text{since } K \geq 4 \\
&= K^2 + 2K + 2(\color{red}{K}) \\
&\geq K^2 + 2K + 2(\color{red}{4}) &\text{since } K \geq 4 \\
&> K^2 + 2K + 1 &\text{since } 8 > 1 \\
&= (K+1)^2
\end{align*}
as desired. $~~~\blacksquare$

Comment: This is very clear. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your last line is unjustified. You shouldn't write anything that you haven't justified. Instead, you can write "If $2^K > K^2$, then $2^{K+1}$ ...".

Answer (score 0):

You need to show: $2K^2 \geq (K+1)^2$

Comment: Okay, and thank you for editing my question! Still learning how to ask questions properly.